# Highcharts - xAxis label for each point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Question: "Is there a way to force an xAxis label for each point?"**

Basically, I have a time series and I need to label Every point on the xAxis... These points could be at any interval.

[image: Highcharts xAxis label every point problem]

Answer (score 0):

The setting you need to chaange is 'tickInterval' (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval).

Assuming the axis is of type 'datetime', and you want an interval of 1 day, and the times are in milliseconds, you will need:

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval:60*60*24* 1000,
}
```

If you need even more control over the labels, you can supply an array of tickPositions or write a tickPositioner function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner).

In your case, it may be easier to supply the tickPositions option, as you can just loop over your data getting the x-axis values and create an array of the datetime values.

```
    xAxis: {
        tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8]
    },
```

Comment: `tickInterval` sets a fixed interval.  This needs to work even if there is a point on Monday, Tuesday then Thursday then Sunday.  All of those days should be on the xAxis (Wednesday Friday and Saturday should not show).

Comment: Updated my answer to include info about tickPositions.

Comment: Looked at this as well, this way I would have to set each Label manually.  And since data is dynamically updated, this can be a bit troubling.

Comment: I don't think you have a choice. If it's dynamic, using the tickPositioner function may work better.